# How to instantiate an comparison function (functor) when defining a map/set?

Tags: c++, std, functor, multiset

I'm using a funciton object to specify a comparison function for map/set:

```
struct CompareObject {
    bool operator()(Node* const n1, Node* const n2) const;
};
```

As far as I understand defining a set like this will not create any instance of CompareObject and will pretend it is static:

```
std::multiset<Node*, CompareObject> set;
```

But in my problem I need to pass an instance of Tree to it for I'm using it in the actual comparision function:

```
bool
CompareObject::operator()(Node* const n1, Node* const n2) const {
  if (tree->getNoOfGood(n1) > tree->getNoOfGood(n2)) return false;
  if (tree->getNoOfGood(n2) > tree->getNoOfGood(n1)) return true;
  return false;
}
```

So, I'm adding some fields to CompareObject definition:

```
struct CompareObject {

  Tree& tree;              // added
  CompareObject(Tree& t);  // added

  bool operator()(Node* const n1, Node* const n2) const;
};
```

The issue I'm having is that I don't know how to instatiate this object with definition of the set.

The first thing that comes to my mind is:

```
std::multiset<Node*, CompareObjects(*this)> shapesMap; // not valid code
```

but not suprisingly it gives me an error: *‘this’ cannot appear in a constant-expression*

Do you have any ideas how to go around this problem?

Comment: Note a difference between `Node*const n` and `Node const *n` and `const Node* n`. In the first case `const` applies to pointer, so we cannot make `n` to point to another object, but can change data under this pointer: `n->x=22` is possible. 2nd and 3rd notations don't allow to change object under pointer. *You may want use 2nd or 3rd variant.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass in an instance of the functor as a parameter to the set constructor. So something like `multiset<Node*, CompareObject> shapesSet(CompareObject(myTree));`

Comment: @msgmaxim I think the compiler might be parsing the initialization as a function declaration. Try adding an extra set of brackets around CompareObject: `multiset<Node*, CompareObject> shapesSet((CompareObject(myTree)));`. If you are using C++11, you can also use uniform intialization: `shapesSet{CompareObject{myTree}};`

Comment: Additional brackets didn't help, but uniform initialization seem to solve this problem. Btw, initializer lists works fine, too!